# Как сделать переход на другую строку в GET-запросе через OkHttp?

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, get, jsoup, okhttp

Формирую сообщение для отправки через VkAPI, пытаюсь поставить переходы на другую строку и делаю GET-запрос через OkHttp, но сообщение приходит склеенное.

***Что я хочу получить:***

Сайт: websiteName

Описание: Description

***Что я получаю:***

Сайт: websiteName Описание: description

***Как отправляется GET-запрос:***

```
String message = "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=91215491&v=5.52&message=" + "Сайт: " + websiteName + "\n" + "Описание: " + description + "&access_token=TOKEN";
client.setConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//Connect timeout
client.setReadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//Socket timeout

Request request = new Request.Builder().url(message).build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Также пробовал через \r\n и на всякий случай через String Builder, но проблема именно с OkHttp, ибо через тот же jsoup теста ради запрос отправлялся нормально и переносы приходили отлично.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `"\n"` на `"%0A"`

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нужно было заменить "\n" на "%0A".

Comment: Этот вариант решает проблему лишь частично. В подставляемых переменных, вообще говоря, может быть что угодно. Неплохо бы их тоже закодировать.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключалась в неэкранировании специальных символов в URI. Прежде чем передавать текст сообщения, закодируйте его процентами. Вот так

```
String messageText = "Сайт: " + websiteName + "\nОписание: " + description;
String encodedMessage = URLEncoder.encode(messageText, "ISO-8859-1");
String requestUrl = "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?v=5.52&access_token=TOKEN&user_id=91215491&message=" + encodedMessage;
...
```

Также рассмотрите возможность использования [разнообразных построителей URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html).